# zsh: insert last argument of previous command

Tags: command-line, zsh

I recently switched from bash to zsh.  When typing a new command in bash (in vi mode), if I type Esc-_ (escape underscore), it inserts the last argument of the previous command. I want to do the same thing in zsh.  (Currently, it just beeps at me.)  How can I get what I want?

Answer (score 0):

`ESC-_` is more of an `emacs`-style key binding, but if you want to add it as well to the `vi`-style insert mode, you can do:

```
bindkey -M viins '\e_' insert-last-word
```

(best in `~/.zshrc`).

If you also want `_` in cmd mode to insert the last word after the cursor and switch to insert mode like `bash` and `ksh93` seem to be doing (the undocumented `vi-yank-arg` widget in `bash`), you could do:

```
vi-yank-arg() {
  NUMERIC=1 zle .vi-add-next
  zle .insert-last-word
}
zle -N vi-yank-arg
bindkey -M vicmd _ vi-yank-arg
```

Which like in `emacs` mode would append the `$NUMERIC`<sup>th</sup> last word from the previous command (`bash` and `ksh93` seem to ignore the numeric argument).

Comment: Actually, it's just `_`.  The ESC is switching to vi command mode.  Which means that `vicmd` is the correct map.

Comment: That's _almost_ right. When I add that, it deletes any trailing space (even if I typed one explicitly) and adds the last word. So if I did `echo foo` followed by `echo <Esc>-_` it becomes `echofoo` with no space. How can I get it either to leave existing whitespace alone or, if none, add 1 space?

Comment: @JdeBP, presumably the OP wants to use `ESC-_` in insert mode and remain in insert word to emulate an emacs-style behaviour like in `bash`/`ksh`

Comment: @PaulJ.Lucas, I can't reproduce here with zsh 5.7.1. If you can't reproduce it either under `zsh -f`, then you might have other customisation that conflicts with that.

Comment: @JdeBP, I see now that `bash`'s and `ksh93`'s `_` (but not mksh's) in cmd mode inserts the last word after the cursor **and goes into insert mode**

Comment: @JdeBP, see edit. In bash/ksh93 `Alt+_` in insert/replace mode inserts the last word like in emacs mode and then goes into insert mode. They obviously didn't think it through.

Comment: I tried with `zsh -f` and get the same behavior with 5.7.1 (on macOS, if it matters). I also tried your `vi-yank-arg` version and also get `echofoo` (no space).

Comment: I just tried adding `zle .magic-space` as the second line in `vi-yank-arg` and that seems to work. BTW: can you explain a bit? What is the `NUMERIC=1` for? What are the `.` (dots) for?

Comment: @Paul, I noticed `bash` inserts an extra space (as in `ESC-_` inserts a space followed by the last arg), is that possibly what you expect?

Comment: @Paul I don't think `magic-space` is what you want here. If you want to append a space character at the current cursor position, you can do `LBUFFER+=' '`